# Prove if Tautology, Contradicton, or Neither. Is my proof ok?

Tags: boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

**Determine whether $((p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow r) \Leftrightarrow (p \Rightarrow (q \Rightarrow r))$ is a tautology, a contradiction, or neither.**

If $p,q,r
 = (0,0,0)$
 then $((p \Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow r)$
 $\Leftrightarrow$
 $(p\Rightarrow(q\Rightarrow r))
 =
 0$, but if $p,q,r
 = (0,0,1)$
  then $((p\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow r)
 \Leftrightarrow
 (p \Rightarrow (q \Rightarrow r))
 =
 1$
  . Therefore it is neither a tautology nor a contradiction.

Is this a good proof? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You might add more detail to show how you inferred both statements, but otherwise your demonstration seems fine.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The truth table gives
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
p&q&r&p\implies q&(p\implies q)\implies r&q\implies r&p\implies (q\implies r)\\
\hline
T&T&T&T&T&T&T\\
T&T&F&T&F&F&F\\
T&F&T&F&T&T&T\\
T&F&F&F&T&T&T\\
F&T&T&T&T&T&T\\
F&T&F&T&F&F&T\\
F&F&T&T&T&T&T\\
F&F&F&T&F&T&T
\end{array}$$

Since there are two rows such that $(p\implies q)\implies r\iff p\implies(q\implies r)$ is not true, then it is not a tautology.  Also since there is at least one row such that those columns are equivalent means that this is not a contradiction.  Therefore, it's neither a contradiction nor a tautology.

Comment: You're right.  Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: @jnh Thanks. The reason I didn't include a truth table is because my lecturer thought that I didn't need too. How would my answer suffice though without a truth table? Thanks for the feedback though!